# Notifications for new questions on our favourite tags

Tags: feature-request, notifications, tag-watching, android-app

It would be very helpful to **receive notifications** via the Android app whenever a new posted question is tagged with one of our **favourite tags**. An option could be placed in the settings menu to toggle the feature on/off.

This will allow us to be immediately alerted to read and respond to new questions whenever we are, and even when we do not have the site open on the browser, or *keeping the app open and continuously refreshing the list of new questions*.

I mean, this is what phone apps do nowadays to keep users engaged right?

Perhaps a list of all our favourite tags on all sites could be displayed in a menu, and we can select *only those we want notifications for*.

Comment: I think this should be disabled for Stack Overflow, but I would not be opposed to having it enabled on smaller sites.

Answer (score 1):

I like this idea, except when you get to Stack Overflow (and probably SU and SF too), the amount of notifications would be insane... I suggest we allow fine tuned controls so that on  we can choose to have the notifications be immdiate, 15 minutes, 1 hour, 12 hours, etc (aribtrary times, more options could be added or even user chosen times). This way one could have it so that smaller sites have the notification go off immediately but on larger sites it could be the users preference.

Comment: This is less useful for tags with a lot of action (like Java or JavaScript, where questions are coming in every single minute), but it's extremely useful for smaller niche tags.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to post my own question about these notifications in the Android app, but I got linked to this one. Hopefully this "answer" bumps the request, as I'd be very curious to hear about any updates to this, or alternative ways to get mobile notifications.

My main action on Stack Overflow is lurking in a niche tag, waiting for new questions, and answering them. The tag gets probably less than 10 questions per day.

In a desktop browser, this is pretty easy- I get a little (1) notification in the browser tab when I leave it on the page for the tag.

If I got a notification from the Android app for new questions, I would use it every day. As of now, I'm going to uninstall it.

Comment: Thank you for your input Kevin, I do hope they will implement it soon. I have been waiting 3 years for this to happen.