# Save favourite groups of tags in Android App

Tags: feature-request, tags, android-app

When I use the mobile/desktop site, I have a handful of bookmarks to take me straight to lists of questions I like. For example:

- Newest unanswered questions tagged with [java](/questions/tagged/java) or [junit](/questions/tagged/junit) on Stack Overflow ([bookmark link](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/java+or+junit))
- Newest unanswered questions tagged with [cryptography](/questions/tagged/cryptography), [rsa](/questions/tagged/rsa), [encryption](/questions/tagged/encryption) or [aes](/questions/tagged/aes) on Stack Overflow ([bookmark link](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/aes+or+cryptography+or+rsa+or+encryption))

Note: these are not *favourite tags* on the desktop site. They are just collections of tags that provide me with certain types of question I like to answer.

Would it be possible to add something to the menu in the Android app where we can save links to groups of tags? Perhaps this should be a more general feature, e.g. save the results of a search to a link on the menu.

Note: a related questions is [Notifications for new questions on our favourite tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191335/notifications-for-new-questions-on-our-favourite-tags) , but this focuses on use of favourite tags, which misses the benefits of *groups* of tags.

Comment: It's indeed required feature because every time we have to search for our favourite tags manually :(