# Easily choose tags to search on

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I commonly search on a handful of tags and entering  square brackets on the phone sucks. It would be great to easily select one or more tags and run the search.

Comment: Related / similar: [Save favourite groups of tags in Android App](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212571)