# Can we merge [tag-watching] and [favorite-tags]?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, meta, retag-request

It has been a while since [favorite tags were renamed to Tag watching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312180/357396) and some new features were added. When that happened, a new tag [tag-watching] is created. This was created as a master tag of already present [favorite-tags](/questions/tagged/favorite-tags).

However, there is some inconsistency after this process.

- There are many old questions tagged with [favorite-tags](/questions/tagged/favorite-tags) like this one [Notifications for new questions on our favourite tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191335/357396) So, merge these tags.
- In the [tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags) section, it shows that there are 420 questions with [favorite-tags](/questions/tagged/favorite-tags) and only 16 with [tag-watching](/questions/tagged/tag-watching). When we click on former, we see all 420 questions. But the hover and tags give a wrong count.
- While we write a question, we are shown tag suggestions. When we write questions on this topic i.e,. favorite tags, we are suggested the synonym [favorite-tags](/questions/tagged/favorite-tags) but not the master tag [tag-watching](/questions/tagged/tag-watching). Is this also caused due to the same reason

> [image: Tag suggestions showing synonym instead of master tag]

To solve this, can we merge both these tags?

This is a request asking merge of these two tags different from asking why is a tag synonym showing up on a question. By performing merge, inconsistency in showing number of questions in search and tags section will be solved.

Comment: @animuson My question was not only about questions shown with synonyms. What about second and third points? Do we see tag suggestions of tag synonyms while posting questions? It is also a retag question to merge those tags.

Comment: Yes, so long as the tags have not been merged, the old tag functions fully as a normal tag in all aspects. The *only* thing a synonym does is rewrite the tag to its master when you submit the post.

Comment: It looks like these tags were merged at some point, so I've retagged this as [status-completed].

Answer (score 5):

Merges require a moderator, but this seems like a useful request.  If having a favorite-tags synonym is useful, it can be re-added *after* the merge, so all the questions will be on [tag-watching](/questions/tagged/tag-watching) where they won't confuse the tag suggestions and tags list.  (I don't know if favorite-tags is still useful, but it might be because it takes people a while to adapt to new terminology.  I still see references occasionally to the supercollider!)